# upload and download files from ftp using Unix script

Tags: unix, ftp

Below is the code that was used when we used .netrc file. But now we 
     can't use auto login.So have to manually read the .netrc file and fetch 
     username and password.This is generic download script will download files 
     from server. I need some help in converting this script to read the file 
     and fetch the username and password.

```
  . $HOME/env
  . $LIB_PATH/miip_functions.shl
   OPTIND=1;ftpop=;user=;hosts=;quote=
  while getopts h:f:n:q: arg
  do
   case $arg in
     h)  hosts="$OPTARG"
     ;;
    f)  hosts=`cat $OPTARG`
      ;;
    n)  ftpop=-n
     user="user $OPTARG"
       ;;
   q)  quote="$OPTARG"
   ;;
       \?) logMessage ERROR "download.shl was used incorrectly."
       endRun 1
      ;;
  esac
 done
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`
 if [ $# -ne 2 ] ; then
  logMessage ERROR "download.shl was used incorrectly."
  endRun 1
  fi
 dataset="'$1'"
  filename=$2
 file=`basename $2`
 if [ -z "$hosts" ] ; then
  hosts=`cat $LIB_PATH/ftp.hosts 2> /dev/null`
  if [ -z "$hosts" ] ; then
      hosts="ftp.test ftp.test2"
   fi
      fi
     logMessage DLOAD "Starting FTP download of $file."
      for host in $hosts
     do
    ftp -v $ftpop $host << ! > $TMPFILE.ftp 2>&1
      $user
      $quote
     get $dataset $filename
      !
      egrep '^421 |^425 |^426 |^450 |^451 |^452 |^530 |^531 |^550 |^551 
     |^552|^553 |^590 |^Not connected' $TMPFILE.ftp > /dev/null 2>&1
        rtn=$?
       if [ $rtn -eq 1 ] ; then 
         break
         fi
      done

    (echo ; echo -------------- ; echo $PROGNAME ; echo --------------) >> 
  $RUNFILE
  cat $TMPFILE.ftp >> $RUNFILE
     rm -f $TMPFILE.ftp

    if [ $rtn -eq 1 ] ; then
     logMessage DLOAD "Completed FTP download of $file."
    else
      logMessage ERROR "Download of $file failed."
      fi
       `
```

Comment: Maybe .netrc can help you. You can store host specific informations for automatic logging. `man netrc`

Comment: hey Alain, i have a .netrc file now. so i guess if i just give the ftp name it should automatically log in.

Comment: If user name and password is correct, yes.

Comment: Hey Alain, i can't use .netrc file as in my server i cannot do 600 .I need to lookup on a file for username and password and then perform ftp.Can you give me some idea on how to do it.

Comment: I have a .netrc file. But i need to do a lookup on .netrc file to get username and password from there and pass that in my script

Comment: No. Unless ftp is called with -n, there is an attempt to autologing. You juste have to ftp ftp.site.com and ftp reads ~/.netrc. If it finds an entry ftp.site.com, it tries to auto log in with the user and password associated  with site name.

Comment: Alain. I have added the code i used  when auto login was used. I need to now read the file and fetch username and password and use that in the script. 
  machine ftp.test login test1 password test2

I need to read ftp.test from my script and fetch test1 and test2 to do ftp.